# Hot to get live streaming data in android

Tags: android, streaming, live

I am trying to make an app which gets livestreaming camera videos. I can stream my webcam from my laptop on the ip (for example ip:176.33.226.53:8070), by using the 1AVStreaming program but I can't reach the streaming video in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Media Player can directly work with the url itself.

Look for something like

```
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://your/video/file/path");

    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setDataSource(context, myUri);
    player.prepare();
```

Use MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener to show controls or start the video
Their are various examples available. Just Google It

Comment: Thnx buddy but i need to translate ip:176.33.226.53:8070  to a url..
I wont  get stream on my laptop i'll get it online

Comment: if your phone and your laptop connected to a same network. i think 
url in the form http://176.33.226.53:8070/path/to/your/file should work. make sure your webserver is running properly